# Implicit distances in demonstrative pronouns "das", "dieses", "jenes"

Tags: translation, pronoun

*[For the following, please assume neutral case always to make it simpler.]*

I was lucky enough to grow up in a Spanish-German bilingual household, and as such am fluent in both languages. This is important context for my question.

I'm currently struggling with how to convey, when teaching German to Spanish speakers, the (subtle) differences between the three demonstrative pronouns I know of in German: *das*, *dieses*, and *jenes*. You see, in Spanish, we also have three forms, and they each carry a different, not so subtle, connotation of distance from the speaker; there is one form ("*esto*") which implies that the noun being replaced is *close* - as in I'm holding it, or I could reach out and grab it.

The second form ("eso") implies that the noun is close enough to be easily pointed at and viewed comfortably - at viewing distance, not necessarily grabbing distance.

The third form ("*aquello*") is less frequently used, but still common and it implies the noun to be "over there" - that might be squinting distance, or even out of viewing distance.

My problem is that I would like to map these three connotations to the German demonstrative pronouns, so that Spanish speaking users can easily learn when to appropiately use each one (by knowing which one they would use in Spanish, and taking the equivalent German pronoun).

According to my understanding, I'f im speaking about three objects of the same kind, "*dieses*" is the one I hold in my hand, "*das*" is the one that's a few paces/meters away, and finally "*jenes*" is the one that is a bit further away. I am however worried that because my Spanish language skills developed first (due to a stronger bond with my Spanish-speaking parent), I'm projecting too much of the Spanish connotation onto the German words, and that a "purebred" native German wouldn't agree with me.

Do you consider my assignment of "distance" (which can also be figurative, like how far you are from a goal) to be valid, or does it seem a little off to you?

Comment: I'm afraid but I guess your Spanish had a bad influence on your German ;) "Das hier in meiner Hand", "Das da vorne" and "Das da ganz hinten an der Ecke" are all equally fine". – We recently had [a question](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/15204/1224) that could be of interest for you as it's about the synonymously and frequency of those words.

Comment: Furthermore, be aware that there's a slight difference between theory and praxis. You can read through the theory on different webpages, [like here](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=79), but in praxis "jene-" is most times replaced and if you take "das" or "dieses" sometimes feels a bit arbitrary.

Comment: There are also regularities to do with time rather than place. In written language, if you speak of A and then B, 'dieses' is supposed to refer to B and 'jenes' to A because it was *mentioned earlier* than B - not because it's farther away.

Comment: @KilianFoth It's further away in the written sentence, or further back in time since it was read/heard. In my last sentence, I mention that "distance" does not have to mean *physical distance*, but can also be generalized to how "available" something is.

Comment: @Em1 I know those are all valid sentences; my question is not about correctness but about implied meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eine Zuordnung von Entfernungen zu diesen Pronomen, die den spanischen Regeln äquivalent wäre, gibt es im Deutschen nicht. Em1 hat bereits auf eine [verwandte Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/15204/1224) verwiesen.

Ich möchte anhand von ein paar Beispielen zeigen, daß das Austauschen von "dieses", "das" und "jenes" nicht einfach eine Änderung der physischen oder metaphorischen Distanz bewirkt.

"In diesem Haus bin ich geboren" kannst Du sagen, egal ob Du direkt davor stehst oder aus 10km Entfernung durch ein Fernrohr darauf schaust. Ein deutschsprachiger Außerirdischer könnte sogar sagen "In dieser Galaxie bin ich geboren" (während er auf einen Punkt am Himmel zeigt). Es muß nur sichergestellt sein, daß zwischen Dir und Deinem Gesprächspartner unmißverständlich geklärt ist, um welches Objekt es sich handelt.

"In *dem* Haus [da, dort] bin ich geboren." ist dem vorigen Satz sehr ähnlich. Das erste Beispiel fordert den Zuhörer etwas mehr dazu auf, auf das Haus zu schauen, während dieses hier eher die Sachinformation betont. Es ist auch stilistisch "einfacher" und von daher umgangssprachlich vermutlich häufiger.

"In dem gelben Haus [da, dort] bin ich geboren." Hier ist "gelb" eine Information, die der Identifizierung des Hauses dienen soll ("nicht das rote daneben").

"In diesem gelben Haus bin ich geboren." Hier wird der Zuhörer darauf hingewiesen, daß das Haus gelb ist. Er weiß auch ohne diese Information genau, um welches Haus es sich handelt. (Mit "gelb" als Attribut ist das ein eher konstruiertes Beispiel. Mit "schön" stattdessen wird es praxisnäher und könnte den Stolz des Sprechers ausdrücken, in einem schönen Haus geboren worden zu sein.)

"In München in der Müllerstraße steht ein altes Haus. Es hat... [langatmige Beschreibung] ... In jenem Haus bin ich geboren." Du hast mit Deiner Frage insofern recht, als daß der Gebrauch von "jenes" eine gewisse Distanz voraussetzt. Aber eher in dem Sinne, daß es keine direkte Verbindung gibt zwischen dem Objekt und der aktuellen Situation. Am deutlichsten wird das in dem Gegensatzpaar "Diesseits" und "Jenseits". "Jenes" wird deshalb oft in einem erzählenden Kontext gebraucht (aber beachte Ausnahmen wie "dieser oder jener") und ist vielleicht auch deshalb in der Schriftsprache häufiger als im gesprochenen Deutsch.

Alle drei Pronomen kannst Du auch für Zeitangaben verwenden:

"Dieses Jahr" ist immer das aktuelle Jahr. (Oder zumindest meist - vielleicht kann jemand ein Gegenbeispiel ergänzen?)

"In dem Jahr, in dem Deutschland zum ersten Mal Fußballweltmeister wurde, ..." Der Nebensatz dient hier der Identifizierung des Jahres, der Sprecher setzt also einen fußballinteressierten Zuhörer voraus, der nun weiß, daß es um 1954 geht.

"In jenem Jahr, in dem Deutschland zum ersten Mal Fußballweltmeister wurde, ..." Es wurde vorab schon über 1954 geredet, und der Sprecher möchte nun die Aufmerksamkeit darauf lenken, oder zumindest die Information einstreuen, daß Deutschland in jenem Jahr zum ersten Mal Fußballweltmeister wurde. Formulierungen wie "in jenem Jahr" oder "in jener Zeit" können anstelle von "damals" verwendet werden.

Comment: "Dieses Jahr" ist immer das aktuella Jahr. -> Richtig, aber interessant wird's bei "Dieses Wochenende", wenn gerade *nicht* Wochenende ist. Freitags: Was machst du dieses Wochenende. Montags: Was hast du dieses Wochenende gemacht. – Aber das ist ein ganz anderes Thema. Sorry :D

Comment: @Em1 Ich hatte sowas im Kopf wie "Dieses Jahr wurde für ihn zum erfolgreichsten seiner Karriere", wenn unmittelbar zuvor von einem bestimmten Jahr die Rede war. Ich dachte erst, da müßte man auch "jenes" nehmen, aber mittlerweile denke ich, das geht. Oder? Da entsteht dann einfach ein direkter Bezug, ohne die "es war einmal"-Patina der Variante mit "jenes".

Comment: @Em1 Zu dem "anderen Thema": "Was hast du dieses Wochenende gemacht?" wäre für mich schlicht falsch - "am Wochenende" würden meine Kollegen und ich verwenden - oder "letztes Wochenende", was ähnlich problematisch ist wie "nächstes Wochenende": http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-ein-ums-naechste-mal-a-379039.html Insofern: wirklich interessantes Thema ;-) Ich weiß nur nicht, ob es sich in eine Frage gießen läßt, die "constructive" und nicht "opinion-based" ist, sonst könnten wir das ja mal hier diskutieren.

Comment: Zu 1: Stimmt, war mir entgangen. *Dieses* ist fein, auch wenn es nicht das aktuelle ist. Zu 2: Es gab auf jeden Fall auf ELU dazu mal ne Frage. Welches ist "this weekend". Ob es hier schon eine gab, weiß ich nicht, sie wäre aber nicht opinion-based. Die Antwort wäre aber die gleiche, wie im Englischen ;)

Comment: Danke für die ausführliche Antwort - das Lesen war lehrreich. Was mich allerdings wundert ist warum in keinem Ihrer Beispiele Pronomen, sondern immer nur Adjektive vorkommen - und ich frage mich, inwiefern dies auf meine Frage zutrifft.